# razor: when my model is returned, only one object is returned and not all of them

Tags: asp.net, razor

i have this formfield:

```
<div class="GroupContent">
                                @{
                                    var nr = 0;
                                    foreach (var entry in Model.Languages)
                                    {
                                        <table cellspacing="" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="Label">
                                                    <label for="">language</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="Field">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="Languages[@nr].Id" value="@entry.Id" />
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="Languages[@nr].GlobalTaggingId" value="@entry.GlobalTaggingId" />
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="Languages[@nr].LanguageId" value="@entry.LanguageId" />
                                                    <div class="input-control text">
                                                        <input type="text" name="Languages[@nr].Name" value="@entry.Name" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    }
                                    nr++;
                                }
                            </div>
```

This displays a div with a few localization options.

[image]

Now, if I alter one of them and click save, this is what is returned:

[image]

So, as you can see, the list "Languages" contains only one result. But it should contain 2. My object is being returned correctly, but again; just this one object and not both.

This is my model:

```
public class GlobalTaggingLocalizationModel : CmsBasePopupViewModel
{
    public List <LanguageModel> Languages { get; set; }
}

public class LanguageModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public int GlobalTaggingId { get; set; }
}
```

Why isnt the list with ALL objects being returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the line to increment nr within the languages for loop then your inputs will have unique names.

Comment: urgh, i just realized I put the incr on the wrong line. Thank you, this totally solved this issue.